# Encounter ide internal error when i open my application in android studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I just downloaded the newest version of android studio and installed it according to the instruction.
But when I created a new application with blank activity, I encounter following errors, can anyone help me out? Thanks.
I am pretty sure my java_home is correct and my android studio is up to date. Thanks a lot for any advice.

```
Error while indexing C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\src.zip!\javax\management\NumericValueExp.java
To reindex this file IDEA has to be restarted: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\(mynanme)\.AndroidStudio1.4\system\index\.persistent\trigram.index\values
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\(mynanme)\.AndroidStudio1.4\system\index\.persistent\trigram.index\values
at com.intellij.util.indexing.MapReduceIndex.update(MapReduceIndex.java:394)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.updateSingleIndex(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1744)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.doIndexFileContent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1674)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.indexFileContent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1622)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater$2.consume(UnindexedFilesUpdater.java:101)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater$2.consume(UnindexedFilesUpdater.java:97)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.CacheUpdateRunner$MyRunnable$1.run(CacheUpdateRunner.java:292)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1103)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.CacheUpdateRunner$MyRunnable$2.run(CacheUpdateRunner.java:312)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:449)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.CacheUpdateRunner$MyRunnable.run(CacheUpdateRunner.java:306)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\(mynanme)\.AndroidStudio1.4\system\index\.persistent\trigram.index\values
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.getNonnegativeValue(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:321)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.doGet(PersistentHashMap.java:476)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.get(PersistentHashMap.java:455)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.MapReduceIndex.update(MapReduceIndex.java:366)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Index corrupted
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.hashIndex(IntToIntBtree.java:1101)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.search(IntToIntBtree.java:400)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.locate(IntToIntBtree.java:987)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.access$000(IntToIntBtree.java:383)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.get(IntToIntBtree.java:181)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.getNonnegativeValue(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:313)
... 25 more



java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\(mynanme)\.AndroidStudio1.4\system\index\.persistent\trigram.index\values
at com.intellij.util.indexing.MapReduceIndex.savePersistentData(MapReduceIndex.java:679)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.MapReduceIndex.update(MapReduceIndex.java:401)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.updateSingleIndex(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1744)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.doIndexFileContent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1674)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.indexFileContent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1622)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater$2.consume(UnindexedFilesUpdater.java:101)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater$2.consume(UnindexedFilesUpdater.java:97)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.CacheUpdateRunner$MyRunnable$1.run(CacheUpdateRunner.java:292)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1103)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.CacheUpdateRunner$MyRunnable$2.run(CacheUpdateRunner.java:312)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:449)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.CacheUpdateRunner$MyRunnable.run(CacheUpdateRunner.java:306)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\(mynanme)\.AndroidStudio1.4\system\index\.persistent\trigram.index\values
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.getNonnegativeValue(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:321)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.doContainsMapping(PersistentHashMap.java:540)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.containsMapping(PersistentHashMap.java:531)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.MapReduceIndex.savePersistentData(MapReduceIndex.java:646)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Index corrupted
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.hashIndex(IntToIntBtree.java:1101)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.search(IntToIntBtree.java:400)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.locate(IntToIntBtree.java:987)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.access$000(IntToIntBtree.java:383)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.get(IntToIntBtree.java:181)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.getNonnegativeValue(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:313)
... 26 more

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\(mynanme)\.AndroidStudio1.4\system\index\.persistent\trigram.index\values
at com.intellij.util.indexing.MapReduceIndex.update(MapReduceIndex.java:394)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.updateSingleIndex(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1744)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.doIndexFileContent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1674)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.indexFileContent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:1622)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater$2.consume(UnindexedFilesUpdater.java:101)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater$2.consume(UnindexedFilesUpdater.java:97)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.CacheUpdateRun
```

Comment: maybe this helps: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141937